# SQL Server 2000 Database Monitoring

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have never worked on SQL Server 2000 and I got a requirement to check capture the following information to one particular database.

DBName  CurrentDate SPID    BatchDuration   ApplicationName HostName    LoginName   SQLQuery

I tried the query below but it in first place did not return any information or does not meet the requirement as it does not capture the ApplicationName and SQL Text.

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME(dbid) as dbName
,   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as CurrentDate
,   P.spid
,   right(convert(varchar, 
        dateadd(ms, datediff(ms, P.last_batch, getdate()), '2000-01-01'), 
        121), 12) as 'batch_duration'
,   P.program_name
,   P.hostname
,   P.loginame
,   P.cmd
from master.dbo.sysprocesses P
where P.spid > 50
and      P.status not in ('background', 'sleeping')
and      P.cmd not in ('AWAITING COMMAND'
                ,'MIRROR HANDLER'
                ,'LAZY WRITER'
                ,'CHECKPOINT SLEEP'
                ,'RA MANAGER')
and DB_NAME(dbid) ='master'
order by batch_duration desc
```

Also when I try to setup this script via SQL Agent it only allows to run it every one minutes interval. Is there any other better way to run it like every 5 seconds? or maybe I should be using another method instead e.g. capturing the logins with required information via trigger instead?

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution online: http://strictlysql.blogspot.com/2010/07/lock-monitoring-sql-server-2000.html. Modified the script to fulfill my requirement.

1. Created a table in our monitoring database:

   CREATE TABLE MyDBMonitoring
     (
        DatabaseName        varchar(35),
        Time                   datetime,
        SPID                        INT,
        Query              varchar(1000),
        QueryStatus         VARCHAR(35),
        LoginName           VARCHAR(50),
        HostName            VARCHAR(50),
        LastBatch              datetime,
        Command              VARCHAR(50),
        ProgramName          VARCHAR(100),
        OpenTransactions           INT
     )
2. Modified the script from the link and only selected the fields I need and insert the result into the monitoring table by setting up a SQL Agent Job on the Server. Will provide the result to client in two days.

   CREATE TABLE #sp_lock_details
     (
        spid     INT,
        dbid     INT,
        objid    INT,
        indid    INT,
        TYPE     VARCHAR(100),
        resource VARCHAR(1000),
        mode     VARCHAR(10),
        status   VARCHAR(50)
     )

   INSERT INTO #sp_lock_details
   EXEC Sp_lock

   DECLARE @id INT
   DECLARE @max INT
   DECLARE @spid INT
   DECLARE @exec_qry VARCHAR(500)
   DECLARE @monitored_dt DATETIME

   SET @monitored_dt = Getdate()

   CREATE TABLE [#sysproc]
     (
        id             INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
        [spid]         [SMALLINT] NOT NULL,
        [dbname]       NVARCHAR COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as NULL,
        [cpu]          [INT] NOT NULL,
        [memusage]     [INT] NOT NULL,
        [status]       NCHAR COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as NOT NULL,
        [loginame]     NCHAR COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as NOT NULL,
        [hostname]     NCHAR COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as NOT NULL,
        [lastwaittype] NCHAR COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as NOT NULL,
        [last_batch]   [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
        [cmd]          NCHAR COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as NOT NULL,
        [program_name] NCHAR COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as NOT NULL,
        QUERY          VARCHAR(500),
        open_tran      INT
     )
   ON [PRIMARY]

   CREATE TABLE #dbccinfo
     (
        eventype  VARCHAR(255),
        param     INT,
        eventinfo VARCHAR(255)
     )

   INSERT INTO #sysproc
               (spid,
                dbname,
                cpu,
                memusage,
                status,
                loginame,
                hostname,
                lastwaittype,
                last_batch,
                cmd,
                program_name,
                open_tran)
   SELECT spid,
          Db_name(MASTER.dbo.sysprocesses.dbid) AS dbname,
          cpu,
          memusage,
          status,
          loginame,
          hostname,
          lastwaittype,
          last_batch,
          cmd,
          program_name,
          open_tran
   FROM   MASTER.dbo.sysprocesses
   WHERE  spid > 50

   SET @max = @@IDENTITY
   SET @id = 1

   WHILE ( @id <= @max )
     BEGIN
         SELECT @spid = spid
         FROM   #sysproc
         WHERE  id = @id

   ```
     SET @exec_qry = 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), @spid) + ')'

     INSERT INTO #dbccinfo
     EXEC (@exec_qry)

     UPDATE sys
     SET    QUERY = eventinfo
     FROM   #sysproc sys,
            #dbccinfo
     WHERE  @id = id

     TRUNCATE TABLE #dbccinfo

     SET @id = @id + 1
   ```

   END

   INSERT INTO dba.dbo.MyDBAMonitoring
     (
        DatabaseName,
        Time,
        SPID,
        Query,
        QueryStatus,
        LoginName,
        HostName,
        LastBatch,
        Command,
        ProgramName,
        OpenTransactions
     )
     SELECT dbname AS DatabaseName, 
          CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS 'TIME',
          #sysproc.spid AS SPID,
          QUERY,
          #sysproc.status                AS query_status,
          loginame,
          hostname,
          last_batch,
          cmd,
          program_name,
          open_tran
     FROM   #sysproc,
              #sp_lock_details
       WHERE  #sp_lock_details.spid = #sysproc.spid
       and dbname = 'ODS;

   DROP TABLE #dbccinfo
   DROP TABLE #sysproc
   DROP TABLE #sp_lock_details

Comment: Can;t seem to format the code.